# android studio centering text preview doesn't center

Tags: android, kotlin

According to the android dev codelab: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-text-composables?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-1-pathway-3%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-text-composables#8

The section Align Text to Center step 3, if I did what the code snippet showed it should center the text. Except it didn't and I don't know why.

I figured out that if I used the modifier I can align the text to center properly. (the two lines that I commented out). But if I use what the codelab gave me it doesn't align centerly at all.

I am on:
Android Emulator API 34.

Android Studio Hedgehog
Build #AI-231.9392.1.2311.11330709, built on January 18, 2024

Runtime version: 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.

[image: working example]

[image: not working example]

```
package com.example.happybirthday

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.ModalBottomSheet
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import com.example.happybirthday.ui.theme.HappyBirthdayTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            HappyBirthdayTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    GreetingText(message = "Happy Birthday Jack", from ="From Jane" )

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun GreetingText(message: String, from: String, modifier: Modifier= Modifier){
    Column (
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        modifier = modifier.padding(8.dp)
    ) {

        Text(
            text = message,
            fontSize = 20.sp,
            lineHeight = 110.sp,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
               //    modifier= Modifier.padding(16.dp)
              //  .align(alignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally)

        )
        Text(
            text = from,
            fontSize = 20.sp,
            modifier= Modifier.padding(16.dp)
                .align(alignment = Alignment.End)

        )
        Text(
            text = "from",
            fontSize = 20.sp,
            lineHeight = 25.sp,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center

        )
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    HappyBirthdayTheme {
        GreetingText(message ="Happy Birthday Android", from = "from Bob")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem while I was learning jetpack compose. Here's a simple solution to this problem. If you do not want to align using modifier you still need to use it if you have not given it a fixed width or something as it then treats the width as wrap content and hence takes only the space it requires. so you should define `modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()`or provide a width. Then it will solve your problem. Do let me know if t doesn't help.

```
@Composable
fun GreetingText(message: String, from: String, modifier: Modifier= Modifier){
    Column (
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        modifier = modifier.padding(8.dp)
    ) {

        Text(
            text = message,
            fontSize = 20.sp,
            lineHeight = 110.sp,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()

        )
        Text(
            text = from,
            fontSize = 20.sp,
            modifier= Modifier.padding(16.dp)
                .align(alignment = Alignment.End)
               


        )
        Text(
            text = "from",
            fontSize = 20.sp,
            lineHeight = 25.sp,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
          

        )
    }
}
```